# Изменение цвета слов в TextBox

Tags: windows, c++

Привет всем.

Как изменить цвет слова в TextBox1. Только одного слова, например:

> printf

на синий. Чтобы только это слово было синим, а все другие чёрным?

Comment: Хорошо,Angry Bird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего вместо TextBox-а использовать RichEdit. Если все-таки хочется TextBox то

1. написать свой компонент
2. попробовать унаследоваться от TextBox-а и полностью переопределить методы отрисовки.

Comment: Thanks!
You Help My,thanks very!